# Sqlalchemy Unexpected Cascading Delete in Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm getting a strage cascading delete (that I haven't configured) when I delete an item from my database. The category entry corresponding to the deleted item is deleted. How do I stop this from happening?

Here's my database setup:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    """Object holding information about individual registered users"""

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    picture = Column(String(250))


class Category(Base):
    """Object holding information about item categories"""

    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)


class Item(Base):
    """Object holding information about individual catalog items"""

    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(5000), nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = relationship("Category")
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship("User")


engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://********:********'
                       + '/itemcatalog.db', echo=False)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Here's the code the triggers the delete:

```
@app.route('/item/<int:item_id>/delete/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def delete_item(item_id):
    item = session.query(Item).filter_by(id=item_id).one()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        session.delete(item)
        session.commit()
        flash('Item Successfully Deleted')
        return redirect(url_for('show_catalog'))
    else:
        return render_template('deleteitem.html', item=item,
                               username=login_session['username'],
                               picture=login_session['picture'])
```

The expected behavior is for only the item specified by its "id" to be deleted, and for there to be no changes to the other tables.

The actual result I get is for the item to be deleted, and the entry in the category table corresponding to this item is also deleted.

UPDATE:

The steps I'm taking are:

1. Creating a new item in the database
2. Deleting that item

The logs that show this, (and the delete) follow.

Adding the new item:

```
2017-12-06 19:32:16 UTC [5383-22] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: SELECT category.id AS category_id, category.name AS category_name 
    FROM category
2017-12-06 19:32:16 UTC [5383-23] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO item (name, description, category_id, user_id) VALUES ('Coffee', 'tasty beverage', 3, 2) RETURNING item.id
2017-12-06 19:32:16 UTC [5383-24] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: COMMIT
2017-12-06 19:32:16 UTC [5383-25] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2017-12-06 19:32:16 UTC [5383-26] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: SELECT category.id AS category_id, category.name AS category_name 
    FROM category ORDER BY category.name ASC
2017-12-06 19:32:16 UTC [5383-27] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.name AS item_name, item.description AS item_description, item.category_id AS item_category_id, item.user_id AS item_user_id 
    FROM item ORDER BY item.name ASC
```

Deleting the new item:

```
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-30] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.name AS item_name, item.description AS item_description, item.category_id AS item_category_id, item.user_id AS item_user_id 
    FROM item 
    WHERE item.id = 7
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-31] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: SELECT category.id AS category_id, category.name AS category_name 
    FROM category 
    WHERE category.id = 3
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-32] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.name AS item_name, item.description AS item_description, item.category_id AS item_category_id, item.user_id AS item_user_id 
    FROM item 
    WHERE 3 = item.category_id
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-33] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: UPDATE item SET category_id=NULL WHERE item.id = 5
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-34] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: UPDATE item SET category_id=NULL WHERE item.id = 6
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-35] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: DELETE FROM item WHERE item.id = 7
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-36] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: DELETE FROM category WHERE category.id = 3
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-37] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: COMMIT
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-38] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-39] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: SELECT category.id AS category_id, category.name AS category_name 
    FROM category ORDER BY category.name ASC
2017-12-06 19:33:14 UTC [5383-40] vagrant@itemcatalog.db LOG:  statement: SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.name AS item_name, item.description AS item_description, item.category_id AS item_category_id, item.user_id AS item_user_id 
    FROM item ORDER BY item.name ASC
```

From the logs I can see its not behaving the way I want it to, but I'm at a loss as to what to change to stop this behavior.

Comment: Is there any chance you can reproduce this in an interactive python session so we can see (a) exactly what code is triggering this behavior and (b) which sqlalchemy logs correspond to which python statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response larsks, and sorry for the confuion. My mistake was a silly one… I created a new database setup file for testing purposes, and forget to update the path to it in my main app.py file.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you have described.  If I put your database setup into `model.py` and then run the following:

```
from model import engine, User, Category, Item
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

s = Session()

c = Category(id=1, name='Misc')
u = User(id=1, name='example', email='example@example.com')

s.add(c)
s.add(u)
s.commit()

i1 = Item(id=1, name='foo', description='foo desc', category=c,
          user=u)
i2 = Item(id=2, name='bar', description='bar desc', category=c,
          user=u)

s.add(i1)
s.add(i2)
s.commit()
```

And then subsequently delete one of the items:

```
>>> item = s.query(Item).filter_by(id=2).one()
2017-12-06 12:11:34,608 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2017-12-06 12:11:34,609 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.name AS item_name, item.description AS item_description, item.category_id AS item_category_id, item.user_id AS item_user_id 
FROM item 
WHERE item.id = %(id_1)s
2017-12-06 12:11:34,609 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'id_1': 2}
>>> s.delete(item)
>>> s.commit()
2017-12-06 12:11:44,915 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine DELETE FROM item WHERE item.id = %(id)s
2017-12-06 12:11:44,916 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'id': 2}
2017-12-06 12:11:45,014 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

You can see that there is only a single `DELETE` statement executed by postgresql, and if we check the referenced `Category` still exists:

```
>>> s.query(Category).get(1)
2017-12-06 12:12:58,968 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2017-12-06 12:12:58,970 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT category.id AS category_id, category.name AS category_name 
FROM category 
WHERE category.id = %(param_1)s
2017-12-06 12:12:58,971 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_1': 1}
<model.Category object at 0x7f42dfab1550>
```

If you are seeing different behavior, can you update your question with a specific sequence of steps that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated the post to provide more information.